# C++ method for Diskpart list disk

Tags: c++, windows, disk

If I run diskpart and give it the command list disk, then it shows me a table like

```
Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt 
--------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---

Disk 0    Online          100 GB      0 B           
Disk 1    Online         3000 GB      0 B        *  
Disk 2    No Media           0 B      0 B           
Disk 3    Foreign         500 GB   490 GB   *         
Disk 4    No Media           0 B      0 B
```

How can I obtain obtain such a list using C++?

Comment: Already had a look at `WMI` ? See what `wmic logicaldisk get *` returns and then call the WMI API from C++ (I bet there are examples here on SO)

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

1. Get a list of disks using GetLogicalDriveStrings().  You can filter for removable or fixed disks with this call.
2. Get a handle to each Volume using something like the following.

   ```
   HANDLE hVolume = CreateFile(volumeName, access, FILE_SHARE_READ |    FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
   ```
3. Get the Disk Number using the volume handle.  I cant remember if you need to lock/unmount the volume for this next bit but those are well documented and easy to do now that you have the volume handle.

   ```
       STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;
       DWORD dwBytesReturned = 0;
       if (!DeviceIoControl(hVolume, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn), &dwBytesReturned, NULL)){

   }

   return sdn.DeviceNumber;
   ```